# Error ITMS-90680:The binary you uploaded was invalid

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I know the question has been posted, but no one answered. I uploaded the .ipa into iTunes Connect through Xcode and Application Loader many times. But every time it failed. Alert messages is:

> Error ITMS-90680:The binary you uploaded was invalid.

Comment: which Xcode version you are using?

Comment: xcode version is 7.3.1

Comment: try again ? lot of users were reporting similar problem. Should be able to submit now

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this error by removing the need for a particular third party library: GPUImage.

Comment: in my project,i use the framework written by swift ,which can lead to the problem?

Comment: We downloaded a fresh copy of the third party library and installed it directly into the projecting using xcode.  Previously we kept the library in SVN.  We suspect the problem is either: corruption of the library in SVN or setting were not correct in xcode during the build.

Comment: the complex problem,maybe i can try again